# How do I convert a sparse matrix in a pandas dataframe to a dense one?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe which contains rows in the format of `(userId, movieId, rating)`. UserIds and movieIds are arbitrary strings.

I want to convert it to dense matrix of dimensions `(# of users, # of movies)` where each cell is `rating` if that row existed in the first and `0` otherwise.

How can I do that in pandas / numpy?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html  is your friend!  You can convert with an average or mode or median rating for you data...

Comment: pivot_table seemed to add a MultiIndex or something but I did found pivot() which did what I want so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to do it by using `pivot()` like so:

```
matrix.pivot(index='userId', columns='movieId', values='rating').fillna(0.0)
```